# Netgear router VLAN setup

Tags: router, vlan, fiber

I recently had a fibre connection installed, and as usual it comes with a crappy router which I wish to replace.

The provided setup is a fibre modem (Huawei HG8240) with WAN output to the ISP supplied router (Comtrend Gigabit) I wish to replace. Before getting the fibre installed I had a Netgear ADSL router and a WiFi range extender (WN2000RPT). I have purchased a new Netgear WAN router (WNDR4000) and am unable to set it up correctly.

I have done some [research](http://www.lostinsantcugat.com/2011/10/replacing-my-crappy-movistar-fiber.html) and apparently my provider (Movistar Spain) requires that the router set the **VLAN Mux Id** to 6. On the linked site he is using a different router (also Netgear) and said it's not possible with the standard firmware. I have no idea how to do this on the Netgear, or if it is even possible.

1. How can I set this up on the Netgear router?
2. If I can't, am I able to install something like Tomato firmware onto both the router **and** the WiFi range extender so I can achieve a desirable setup? Any pointers to instructions online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing dd-wrt on your router to give it many extra capabilities to configure things such as this, making sure your modem is set to bridged mode, and possibly getting in touch with your ISP to verify what settings/vlan etc you need to be on depending on their set up.

Here is a link to a tutorial on installing dd-wrt onto your router: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNDR4000

I have used dd-wrt for a long time in many successful setups. I currently have a cable modem in bridged mode in front of my router running dd-wrt, dynamic dns so I have have a domain name and run servers at home

Basically, you need to upgrade your router's firmware from its upgrade page using the dd-wrt build that has your router's model number in it to break free of the router default firmware. Then you need to flash a standard version of dd-wrt to gain standard features. The trailed build (with your model number in the name) will work great for it, so you don't necessarily need to flash again.